# Copy access control properties from one file to another C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to copy access control properties (which user can read the file, execute, modify, full control, etc) from one file to another. This is my code:

```
private void SetAccessControl(string originalFname, string newFname)
{
    FileSecurity fSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(originalFname);
    File.SetAccessControl(newFname, fSecurity);
}
```

It's not working. How do I do this?

Comment: What's *not* working? Any exception?

Answer (score 0):

if set to a different account to your own, requires backup operator or admin rights, if impersonation isn't used.

Comment: There isn't any, it executes without raising an error. But when I look at the file properties, security tab, I see that access control properties haven't been copied.

Comment: do you have any entries in the event log?